# Perfect Java code to determine a Double is a Perfect Square or not?

Tags: java, numbers

I want to determine whether a number (in double) is a perfect square or not. I have used the below code but it fails for many inputs.

```
private static boolean isSquare(double i) {
        double s = Math.sqrt(i);
        return ((s*s) == i);
    }
```

When `s` results in scientific form, the code fails. For example when `s` is `2.719601835756618E9`

Comment: What do you mean by "in exponential form"?

Comment: And "generally" fails?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'exponential form' for a `double.` There is *scientific notation* for the *string representation* of a `double,` as determined for example by `Double.toString().` Your question lacks precision and detail. Please amend.

Comment: I have edited my question, please comment if anything more needs to be added, or else you can just give me the code which will perfectly determine any double value is a perfect square or not

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from using double due to the rounding problem, try using BigDecimal instead.

Comment: This is the [actual program](https://gist.github.com/ramswaroop/9444697) which is a solution to this [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/is-fibo) which fails for many test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no attempt to test whether the square root of the number is an integer. Any nonnegative real number is the square of some other real number; your code's result depends entirely on floating-point rounding behavior.

Test whether the square root is an integer:

```
if (Double.isInfinite(i)) {
    return false;
}
sqrt = Math.sqrt(i);
return sqrt == Math.floor(sqrt) && sqrt*sqrt == i;
```

The `sqrt*sqrt == i` check should catch some cases where a number exceptionally close to a square has a square root whose closest `double` approximation is an integer. I have not tested this and make no warranties as to its correctness; if you want your software to be robust, don't just copy the code out of the answer.

UPDATE: Found a failing edge case. If an integer double has a greatest odd factor long enough that the square is not representable, feeding the closest double approximation of the square to this code will result in a false positive. The best fix I can think of at the moment is examing the significand of the square root directly to determine how many bits of precision it would take to represent the square. Who knows what else I've missed, though?

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson: Try it with `i=Math.nextAfter(1e44, 1e55)`. It passes the `i != Math.floor(i)` and `sqrt == Math.floor(sqrt)` checks, but it's not a perfect square. The last check catches it.

Comment: Oh, right. Why is the if statement needed? Isn't it impossible for the square of an integer to be anything but an integer? +1s for the rest and your comment.

Comment: Refer this [link](https://gist.github.com/ramswaroop/9444697) and see why your answer doesn't work here. I have mentioned all the test cases.

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson: I don't think it is needed. I threw it in in a half-hearted fit of premature optimization. It probably doesn't even help. Like I said, if you want your software to be robust, it's not a good idea to blindly copy this.

Comment: @Ramswaroop: Your function *still* doesn't test whether the square root is an integer. It only tests whether the original number is an integer. Note the `sqrt == Math.floor(sqrt)` check.

Comment: @user2357112, I have updated the code but it still fails for some inputs, see comment in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/ramswaroop/9444697/#comment-1187225).

Comment: @Ramswaroop: That failure has nothing to do with the square-testing code. That test case fails because you're getting arithmetic overflow in `isFibo`.

Comment: sorry @user2357112 but I am not getting any arithmetic overflow error at my end.

Comment: @Ramswaroop: You certainly are. Try printing `5*i*i`. You'll get a result that makes no sense.

Comment: @user2357112, i got a number like this, `1067793674483130832`. Can you help me find what's wrong in my code in [IsFibo gist](https://gist.github.com/ramswaroop/9444697/)

Comment: @Ramswaroop: You're trying to square numbers whose squares don't fit in a long. You'll need to avoid needing to do that somehow. If you want help with your fibonacci code, ask another question. This discussion has gone far beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: I'm not convinced of the correctness of this answer.  Can you prove that it works for very large numbers, that are beyond the point where every integer is exactly representable by a `double`?  I fear there may be some very large perfectly square integers that are exactly representable by a `double`, but whose square roots are not exactly representable by a `double`.  For me to believe that this answer is correct, I'd need to see some proof that there are no such numbers.

Comment: @DavidWallace: An integer is representable with 53 bits of precision if and only if its greatest odd factor is at most 53 bits long. The square root of a representable integer will have a greatest odd factor that is the square root of its square's greatest odd factor, so the square root's greatest odd factor will be at most 53 bits long (in fact much less). Since the square root's exponent will also fit in the representable range, the square root should be representable. That said, I make no warranties as to the correctness of this code. In fact, it fails for positive infinity.

Comment: Changed the `if` statement to check for infinities, removing premature optimization and catching an edge case. Still haven't actually tested it, though.

Comment: OK, I am convinced by your comment (the longish one) and I have upvoted this.  I think you should edit that comment into the answer itself though - it really is an integral part (no pun) of the answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace: The code still isn't quite correct, though. I found another edge case I missed. A representable integer can have a square that isn't representable. If you take the closest double approximation of the square of such a number and feed it through this code, it will report a false positive. I *think* this can be fixed by examining the significand of the square root directly and determining whether precision loss would occur when it's squared. Who knows what else I might miss, though?

Comment: I see what you mean.  Do you think I should retract my upvote?

Comment: @DavidWallace: I dunno. I've tried to make it clear from the start that even I don't trust this code. Precise analysis of floating-point algorithms is hard.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really serious.  I think I might give this a whole lot more thought though, and post my own solution if I can think of one.  I wouldn't like to post an answer though without being certain that it was correct in every detail, or at least stating which details had been missed.  (For example, the OP probably doesn't care whether or not a posted algorithm gives -0 as a square or not).

Answer (score 0):

static boolean checkPerfectSquare(double x)
    {

```
// finding the square root of given number 
double sq = Math.sqrt(x); 

/* Math.floor() returns closest integer value, for
 * example Math.floor of 984.1 is 984, so if the value
 * of sq is non integer than the below expression would
 * be non-zero.
 */
return ((sq - Math.floor(sq)) == 0); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know that the question is old, but I would post my solution anyway:

```
return Math.sqrt(i) % 1d == 0;
```

Simply check if the `sqrt` has decimals.

Comment: Receive a "-1" could be useful because I could learn from my mistakes, but receive it without a reason it has no sense.